# Crontab style recording rules in Prometheus

Tags: cron, prometheus

I'm using Prometheus to collect some metrics every 30s, which is doing a great job. To save some storage space, I also created some recording rules to aggregate these raw metrics to more coarse ones, like `cpu_time:avg1h`.

Now the problem is, I want the aggregation to happen at the beginning of each hour. Is it possible in Prometheus?

Answer (score 2):

There's no such feature in Prometheus, while you can control the interval of rule evaluations the phases are random.

It is generally advised to have your scrape end evaluation intervals the same for the sake of sanity, so I'd suggest using a 30s evaluation interval. Prometheus has pretty good compression, so it's going to be fairly cheap.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The compression may solve the storage space problem, but it brings another problem: how to efficiently do queries like "give me `cpu_time:avg1h` in past 1 month, but choose only one data point in each hour". I don't want to send and display tens of thousands data points since it would consume too many resources in our clients. Is Prometheus optimized for this kind of queries?

Comment: The query_range endpoint's `step` parameter allows you to control how often you  evaluate a query. There's actually a failsafe in place to prevent more than 11k steps being returned at once.

Comment: After some digging of Prometheus's source code, it doesn't seem to be a hard task to add such a feature to Prometheus. I'm thinking adding an optional field `base` to rule group to control the phase explicitly, which would make some difference to the result of `Group.offset()` function (rules/manager.go:266), any advice?

Comment: Such a feature is very unlikely to be accepted, as it'd only work in very niche use cases and break in normal usage.